# facebook connect for mobile ?auth_token

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, cookies

I am building mobile website and I want to integrate facebook connect in my regular site.

I am using facebook connect that uses the cookie for getting the session key, on mobile this  cookies method for getting the session is not recommended, I think.

what I've got so far is that I call to login rest server and then it return to me the

`?auth_token`

I understand that I need to ask using the auth token for session key, how can I accomplish this ?

This is the url that I am using- http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=apikey&v=1.0&next=mysite

Maybe I dont fully understand how to accomplish facebook connect on mobile and there another way.

Answer (score 0):

i am using the .net framework

string authToken = Request.QueryString["auth_token"];
facebook.Schema.session_info s = a.getSession(authToken);

this will resolve my problem

it return the session

thank to me